# What is the logic behind the probability of getting 'four of a kind' in poker?

Tags: probability, poker

> This hand ($5$ cards of $52$) has the pattern $AAAAB$ where $A$ and $B$ are from distinct kinds. The number of such hands is $\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{4} \binom{12}{1} \binom{4}{1}$. The probability is $0.000240$.

$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{4}$ I understand since there are $13$ choices and $4$ cards for that type but I don't understand why it's multiplied by $\binom{12}{1} \binom{4}{1}$.

What is the logic behind $\binom{12}{1} \binom{4}{1}$?

Answer (score 3):

$\binom{12}{1}$ is the choice of the fifth card's rank; it can be any rank but the one chosen for four of a kind, so 12 remain.

$\binom{4}{1}$ is the choice of the fifth card's suit.  It can be any of the four.

Usually I see the four of a kind lineup a little more succinctly:

$$\binom{13}{1}\binom{48}{1}$$

This is equivalent, because $\binom{4}{4}=1$, and $\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{1}=12\cdot4=48=\binom{48}{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are $13\cdot 48$ such hands -- first you choose which of the 13 kinds it is you have all four of; then you choose one of the remaining 48 cards to bring the hand up to five cards.

$\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{1}$ seems to be a roundabout way of counting the 48 remaining cards.

But I don't see where $\binom{13}{4}$ in the text you quote comes from at all.

Comment: Looks like a bad edit; the original has "(13 choose 1)"